# AceFEM higher order elements fail basic test

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen

I was trying to perform a simple test, as some results that we obtained from AceFEM were not matching with the results we obtained from other methods. Here, I have a simple biaxial test on a cube of unit size.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
<< "AceFEM`";

nel = 5;
Ref[nel_] := 2^(nel - 1); nel = Ref@nel;

pload = 0.016;

MeshGeometry[topology_] := Block[{},
   Lx = 1; Ly = 1; Lz = 1; nx = nel ; ny = nel ; 
   nz = nel ;
   (*corner points*)
   p1 = {0, 0, 0};
   p2 = {Lx, 0, 0};
   p3 = {Lx, Ly, 0};
   p4 = {0, Ly, 0};
   p5 = {0, 0, Lz};
   p6 = {Lx, 0, Lz};
   p7 = {Lx, Ly, Lz};
   p8 = {0, Ly, Lz};
   points = {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8};
   SMTAddMesh[Hexahedron[points], "A", topology, {nx, ny, nz}];
   ];

BoundaryRegions[] := Block[{},
   (*0: left face*)
   Γ0 = SMTFindNodes[Polygon[{p1, p4, p8, p5}]];
   n0 = {-1, 0, 0};
   (*1: lower face*)
   Γ1 = SMTFindNodes[Polygon[{p1, p4, p3, p2}]];
   n1 = {0, 0, -1};
   (*2: front face*)
   Γ2 = SMTFindNodes[Polygon[{p1, p2, p6, p5}]];
   n2 = {0, -1, 0};
   (*3: upper face*)
   Γ3 = SMTFindNodes[Polygon[{p8, p5, p6, p7}]];
   n3 = {0, 0, 1};
   (*4: back face*)
   Γ4 = SMTFindNodes[Polygon[{p4, p8, p7, p3}]];
   n4 = {0, 1, 0};
   (*5: right face*)
   Γ5 = SMTFindNodes[Polygon[{p2, p3, p7, p6}]];
   n5 = {1, 0, 0};
   ];

SetDirichletBC[] := (
   SMTAddEssentialBoundary[Γ0, 1 -> 0]; (*Left Face*)
   SMTAddEssentialBoundary[Γ1, 3 -> 0]; (*Lower Face*)
   SMTAddEssentialBoundary[Γ2, 2 -> 0]; (*Front Face*)
   );

SetNeumannBC[] := (
   SMTAddNaturalBoundary[Γ3, 3 -> Polygon[{pload}]];
   SMTAddNaturalBoundary[Γ4, 2 -> Polygon[{pload}]];
   );

top = "O1";
code = "ML:SED3" <> top <> "DFLE" <> top <> "DHooke";
SMTInputData[];
SMTAddDomain["A", code, {"E *" -> 0.316, "ν *" -> 0.49}];
MeshGeometry[top];
SMTAnalysis[];
BoundaryRegions[];
SetDirichletBC[];
SetNeumannBC[];
Displacement = {};
nodeD = SMTFindNodes[Point[{1, 1, 1}, "D"]];

SMTNextStep["λ" -> 1];
While[
  step = SMTConvergence[10^-8, 25, "Analyze"],
  SMTNewtonIteration[];
  ];
If[step =!= False, SMTStatusReport["Analyze"]; Abort[];];
displ = Flatten[SMTNodeData[nodeD, "at"]];
AppendTo[Displacement, Norm[displ]];
SMTAnimationOfResponse[
  "ShowMeshOptions" -> {"Field" -> "Mises stress", "Mesh" -> True, 
    "Contour" -> True, "DeformedMesh" -> True, 
    "BoundaryConditions" -> False}, 
  "LeadingNodePosition" -> {1, 1, 1}];

Displacement
    (* {0.0616101} *)
```

The result (displacement norm at (1,1,1)) `0.061610` was found to be accurate (converged results from Abaqus and custom FE code). But when I change the topology to `O2`,`H2`,`H2S`, I get different results. `O1` and `H1` however produce accurate results. Could someone please let me know if I am missing something trivial, or if there is a bug of some sort.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AceFEM`s `SMTAddNaturalBoundary` applies load linearly, but you have to apply it with same quadratic function as is used in element, thus for higher order elements you have to use load elements to apply load or manualy set load at loaded nodes `SMTNodeData[loadedNodes,"dB",loads]`.

Standard Load elements are availiable in `AceShare` library of `AceFEM` (`Main Library: Continuum model: NB: Natural boundary conditions` to get a list of possibilities). You have to add 2 load domains and meshes, and comment out `SetNeumannBC[]` (or modify it and move before SMTAnalysis). Important is that surface of each solid element matches the load element. The division order matches the order you defined the polygon. I.E. first 2 points of it define direction 1 thus division `{nz,nx}` and `{ny,nx}` has to be used. Below is working code:

```
top = "H2";
code = "ML:SED3" <> top <> "DFLE" <> top <> "DHooke";
SMTInputData[];
SMTAddDomain["A", code, {"E *" -> 0.316, "\[Nu] *" -> 0.49}];
MeshGeometry[top];

rule\[Delta]\[CapitalOmega] = {"H1" -> "S1", "H2" ->"S2","H2S" ->"S2S"};
loadtop = top /. rule\[Delta]\[CapitalOmega];
load = {"ML:", "SE", "NB", loadtop, "ST", "D3", loadtop, "D", "CO"};
SMTAddDomain["LoadY", load, {"qYg *" -> pload}];
SMTAddDomain["LoadZ", load, {"qZg *" -> pload}];

SMTAddMesh[Polygon[{p4, p8, p7, p3}], "LoadY", loadtop, {nz, nx}];
SMTAddMesh[Polygon[{p8, p5, p6, p7}], "LoadZ", loadtop, {ny, nx}];

SMTAnalysis[];
BoundaryRegions[];
SetDirichletBC[];
```

After you solve this you get same Displacement of `0.061610079977345675`. Additionally, if you want to apply the load on O1 or O2 meshes, one has to specify which pattern to use ("P2-X", where X=1-4). The one matching the default O1/O2 meshes is pattern 3. To run for O2 (and P1-3 for O1!) you need to modify `SMTAddMesh` as:

```
SMTAddMesh[Polygon[{p3, p4, p8, p7}], "LoadY", "P2-3", {nx, nz}];
SMTAddMesh[Polygon[{p8, p5, p6, p7}], "LoadZ", "P2-3", {ny, nx}];
```

This yielded result for O2: `0.061610079977345675`.